# Two field division, awk

Tags: math, awk

I've get stuck with (maybe very easy) function in awk: I'm trying to divide two fields row by row with the following code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $43 > 0 && $31 > 0 {$43/$31; print}' file.tsv
```

But I'm getting continuously this error: `fatal: division by zero attempted`, but I've already check that denominator is always distinct from zero (and indeed, I think the code should be discarding zeroes) and I've no idea what's happening... any suggestion, please? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: The input table has this format (`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $31,$43}' file.tsv | head -4`):

```
triCount_PM triSum_altPM
3   25
3   7
3   0
```

Comment: The division doesn't cause anything to be printed; are you hoping to see the value as part of the output? Which part exactly?

Comment: @tripleee, I thought the output was directly the division result... I've also tried this: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $43 > 0 && $31 > 0 {div = $43/$31; print div}'` but the error doesn't disappear.

Comment: Of course not; just trying to clarify what your expected output is. Can you print the values of the first pair of values in an unambiguous form to help us see what your input looks like?

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a one-line file containing two columns? If so, show us the file.

Comment: It's because of the header.

Comment: Thanks, @karakfa, but I've already tried without the header and the error persists...

Comment: I thought arithmetic operations coerce the fields to be numeric, but perhaps not consistent in all versions.

Comment: Sure they are numeric, but strings without numbers convert to zero (even though numeric comparison says they are bigger than zero at least on my Mac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g. `"fnord" > 0` evaluates to true in Awk; you really need to make sure the values are properly numeric. A common trick for coercing a number interpretation is to add zero.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} 0+$43 > 0 && 0+$31 > 0 { print $43/$31 }' file.tsv
```

Just `print` always prints `$0` (which is initialized to the current input line, though you can change it directly or indirectly from your program); to print something else, pass that "something else" as an argument to `print`.

Comment: It seems to work correctly, thanks! One more question: how I could keep those zero lines as blank lines because number of elements before and after the division change a lot. Thanks again!

Comment: You mean print an empty line where these values are not numerical and larger than zero? Add something like `; next } { print ""` before the last closing brace.

Answer (score 1):

The division-by-zero results from the header which does not have numbers for the fields so both fields are zero. To make this work, you need to skip the header (`NR == 1` tests for the first line)

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print "$43/$31"; next} $43>0 && $31>0 {print $43/$31}' file
```